# How do i loop the moveto class before & after my schedule runs def click in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, python-multithreading, pyautogui

I'm trying to figure out how to make the "class moveto():" in the code below run in a loop before & after the 01:00 schedule. Right now everything runs how I want it to except the moveto class runs all 4 pyautogui class moveto functions then waits for def click(): to run at 01:00 instead of continueing the loop. Is there anyway to fix this?

```
import pyautogui
import time
from pyautogui import *
import win32api, win32con
import schedule

class moveto():
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.moveTo(339, 261)
    time.sleep(3)

    pyautogui.moveTo(804, 255)
    time.sleep(3)

    pyautogui.moveTo(129, 751)
    time.sleep(3)

    pyautogui.moveTo(632, 754)
    time.sleep(3)


def click():
    # stops #
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.press('`')

    # Opens #
    pyautogui.click(711, 1057)
    time.sleep(3)

    # clicks on #
    pyautogui.click(161, 266)
    time.sleep(3)

    # Writes #
    pyautogui.click(447, 993)
    pyautogui.typewrite('#')
    time.sleep(3)

    # Sends #
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(3)

    # clicks #
    pyautogui.click(1850, 11)
    print('#')
    time.sleep(3)

schedule.every().day.at("01:00").do(click)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: if you want to run all time then you have to use some loop in `moveto`

Comment: probably you will have to run `shedule` or `moveto` in separated thread.

Comment: it should be `def moveto()` instead of `class moveto()`

Comment: Thank you, this gets me closer to figuring out how to fix the issue. I'll definitely look into threads.

Answer (score 0):

> I forgot about this, I figured out the answer a couple months ago when I originally posted my question. so I'll
> just leave the answer to this question here

```
import pyautogui
import schedule
import time


def job():
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.moveTo(339, 261)
    time.sleep(3)

    pyautogui.moveTo(804, 255)
    time.sleep(3)

    pyautogui.moveTo(129, 751)
    time.sleep(3)


def job2():
    # stops #
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.press('`')

    # Opens #
    pyautogui.click(711, 1057)
    time.sleep(3)

    # clicks on #
    pyautogui.click(161, 266)
    time.sleep(3)

    # Time
    schedule.every(1).seconds.do(job)
    schedule.every().day.at("01:00").do(job2)

while True:
schedule.run_pending()
time.sleep(1)
```

> I hope this helps anybody who has a similar problem.